# Merge overlapping List places in R

Tags: r, list

I have a problem with lists. I have two lists:

`List1:`

```
[[1]]
 [1] 176 177 178 179 180

[[2]]
 [1] 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241
 [21] 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256

[[3]]
 [1] 260 261 262 263 264 265

[[4]]
 [1] 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304

[[5]]
 [1] 393 394 395 396 397 398
```

`List 2:`

```
[[1]]
 [1]  99 100 101 102 103

[[2]]
 [1] 260 261 262 263 264 265

[[3]]
 [1] 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300

[[4]]
  [1] 390 391 392 393 394 395
```

Now I would like to *create a new list* with the `combined overlapping lists of list 1 and list 2`. It should look like this:

`List 3:`

```
[[1]]
 [1] 260 261 262 263 264 265

[[2]]
 [1] 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304

[[3]]
 [1] 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398
```

I would be happy for ideas!

Comment: What do you do if lists from `list1` are overlapping with several lists from `list2` ?

Comment: Then I would like to have all together in one list.

Comment: sounds like you need clustering so it will handle those multiple cases best: define a distance measure that returns `0` or `1` using `%in%`, build a hierarchical tree and cut it at `0.5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives me the result you asked for:

```
list1<-list(176:180, 222:256, 260:265, 293:304, 393:398)
list2<-list(99:103, 260:265, 293:300, 390:395)

result <- list()
for (x1 in list1) {
  for (x2 in list2) {
    if (any(x1 %in% x2)) {
      result[[length(result)+1]] <- union(x1, x2) 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I'm looking for :) I just added: 

list1<-list(176:180, 222:256, 260:265, 293:304, 393:398)
list2<-list(99:103, 260:265, 293:300, 390:395)

result <- list()
sapply(list1, function(x1) {
  sapply(list2, function(x2) {
    if (any(x1 %in% x2)) {
      if(any(x2 %in% x1)){
      result[[length(result)+1]] <<- union(x1, x2) 
      }
    }
  })
})

Answer (score 0):

Sounds that your list are , list of ranges, On idea is to use the `IRanges` package.

You can do something like this:

First I create my ranges:

```
query   <- IRanges(c(176,222,260,293,393),c(180,256,265,304,398))
subject <- IRanges(c(99,260,293,390),c(103,265,300,395))


 query
IRanges of length 5
    start end width
[1]   176 180     5
[2]   222 256    35
[3]   260 265     6
[4]   293 304    12
[5]   393 398     6
subject
IRanges of length 4
    start end width
[1]    99 103     5
[2]   260 265     6
[3]   293 300     8
[4]   390 395     6
```

Than I find Overlaps

```
tree <- IntervalTree(subject)
res <- findOverlaps(query, tree)

res
Hits of length 3
queryLength: 5
subjectLength: 4
  queryHits subjectHits 
   <integer>   <integer> 
 1         3           2        ## third element in 2 second element 
 2         4           3 
 3         5           4
```